# Can't add a new member to team in iTunes connect

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

We have an iOS app that is fully managed in Xcode by the Agent setup in iTunes Connect.

Now, as our team grows, we tried to add a new member who would be responsible for uploading new versions. But we cant succeed in doing this.

In iTunes Connect, this new member is listed under 'Pending Invitations'. The email was sent out and user has accepted the invitation, but status didn't change.
When doing a re-send invitation, the second mail is well received, but clicking on the 'Accept' brings message 'Already a Member'. Status in Itunes Connect stoically stays with listing user under 'Pending Invitations'.

Xcode allows signing in with the new user, but doesnt see it as being a member of the team.
Although having checked the docs carefully, we must have missed something in this process.

Answer (score 0):

If the member don't have a apple id account on his email he should create it before when he accept the invitation, if it's the case you should wait the itunes validation and it's ok.

check the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html) for more details.

Comment: The apple id was well created before the invite was sent.
The problem is that Accept on invitation says 'Already a member of this team', but iTunes Connect stays with 'Pending Invitation'.

Comment: in this case you should contact itunes and wait for reply from him